# JRuby/Nokogiri can't find Java XML libs in Mule ESB 3

Tags: java, ruby, rubygems, jruby, mule

I've having troubles getting the JRuby gem Nokogiri to work. It works in jirb. I'm running Java 6 on Mac OS X Lion. JRuby is 1.6.3.

Do you know how to solve this? Stacktrace:

```
INFO  2011-07-22 19:12:53,520 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Started app 'muleesb3-1.0-SNAPSHOT'                 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljavax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory;
    at nokogiri.XmlDocument.createNewDocument(XmlDocument.java:220)
    at nokogiri.XmlDocument.<init>(XmlDocument.java:96)
    at nokogiri.HtmlDocument.<init>(HtmlDocument.java:57)
    at nokogiri.NokogiriService$2.allocate(NokogiriService.java:239)
    at nokogiri.internals.HtmlDomParserContext.wrapDocument(HtmlDomParserContext.java:121)
    at nokogiri.internals.XmlDomParserContext.parse(XmlDomParserContext.java:209)
    at nokogiri.HtmlDocument.do_parse(HtmlDocument.java:89)
    at nokogiri.HtmlDocument.read_memory(HtmlDocument.java:117)
    at nokogiri.HtmlDocument$s$0$0$read_memory.call(HtmlDocument$s$0$0$read_memory.gen:65535)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:282)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:120)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:272)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:80)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(String, ClassLoader)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) is a new method in Java 6.  It sounds like you have another jar in your classpath that contains an older version of this class.  You can see a potential list of jars that might contain the class at [jarfinder.com](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory).  If you're able to view your project in Eclipse, you could check what jars contain the DocumentBuilderFactory class by using the 'Open Type' dialog.